# Get Title of Clicked Link On Context Menu (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to retrieve the title of a link that is right clicked by the user (when the context menu pops up). I want to retrieve the title of the page they right clicked on to display it, and I can not figure it out. I tried using and AJAX request to the link to get the title from it's src, but all google right clicks are redirect links. Does anyone know how to get the title of the website, either from the redirect link or straight from the context menu?

```
// wipe the context menu so no duplicates
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
    //context menu customization
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Do stuff",
    contexts: ["link"], // ContextType
    onclick: addLinkToList // A callback function that stores the links that were clicked
});
});
```

Above is the code to create the Context Menu. My addlinktolist function stores the link that is clicked but I also want it to get the title of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can extract the original URL with `new URLSearchParams(info.linkUrl).get('url')`, for example.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I actually got it to work, thanks! It is a little hacky.... I basically ran a loop of ajax requests until it found a <title> tag in the response. Then when it found the title response, it grabbed it and moved onto the next link. Its surprisingly fast.... Didnt think it would work that well! I will try to implement your idea, as it seems simpler and shorter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this i made an AJAX request that searches the html of the page for a title tag. If it does not find a title tag, it finds the URL from the google redirect link and then searches for the title tag from the response of that URL.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: links[i],
            complete: function(data) {
                if (data.responseText.includes("<title>")) {
                    title = (data.responseText.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1]);

                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: data.responseText.match(/URL='([^<]+)'"/)[1],
                        complete: function(data2) {
                            title = (data2.responseText.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1]);

                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }); // ajax call to get title of website
```